# Why would the "Helpful content" update dislike my website?

Tags: google

I think the "Helpful content" update has knobbled me for some reason. It hit on the 25th (shown by the line on the chart) and after that, the average position takes a nosedive. It's odd because the content on my site is very helpful!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm preparing materials to put online and I've been looking almost daily for information about "helpful content", as determined by google update. Not yet come across any helpful information as defined by webmasters. Although it looks like the sweet spot is five minute read time? ... https://searchengineland.com/google-search-quick-read-5-min-read-labels-387599 ... 850 to 2500 words seems to get the short read time but Google says word count is not a signal.   I think Google's helpful content is a work in process?

Comment: I looked at your page and source code. Some pages neither graphically looking at it as if I'm illiterate, or semantically in the code clearly define that everything on the is part of a single thing ... Note semantically, "Documentation for the canvas charts" does. While SVG charts semantically has divides of chart-types, Installing and implementing RGraph, a ul of Data import utilities, a ul of Features and examples, with their own headline tag ... my thought is the algo may see this as different <article> not different <section>? But I don't know.

Comment: As a literate human I see the page "SVG charts," as helpful and everything related as a single <article>, but I can not say if the algo sees what I see. It is a question that begs to be answered.

Comment: FYI, it has been confirmed that helpful content is a work in process ... https://searchengineland.com/google-helpful-content-update-isnt-done-387676

Comment: Additionally, after looking through GSC, it seems to have dipped for the most part in the UK. Other regions are performing as they were before the update.